# What is the simplest method for handling VAT for an in-app product in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, billing, tax

I have an in-app product in my app, and I want to offer it to users in countries where Google is responsible for remitting VAT. What is the simplest way to determine the user's country? Or what is the simplest solution to this?

I can't find anywhere in the Play console where I can set the available countries for the in-app product.